# Torus cannot be embedded in $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I've shown that $T^2$ can be embedded in $\mathbb R^3$.
I just can't see why it can not be embedded in $\mathbb R^2$.

Ideas:

1. suppose $F: \mathbb S^1\times \mathbb S^1 \to \mathbb R^2$ is continuous injective then we can construct (somehow) $G:\mathbb S^1\to \mathbb R$ continuous injective so we get a contradiction.
2. we know that $\mathbb R^2$ is homeomorphic to the punctured $2$-sphere, so we get embedding $F$ from $T^2$ to $\mathbb S^2\setminus\{0\}$, thus $F$ is not onto $\mathbb S^2$ and then I can show that it is homotopic to the constant map, but I can't see any contradiction in this situation.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What tools do you have?

Comment: Basic Algebraic Topology

Comment: I know one proof , but that requires some strong algebraic topology tools, namely Alexander Duality.

Comment: It is not so clear what's basic algebraic topology mean. Can you briefly describe that?

Comment: First degree...

Comment: If you know degree that's enough: you have an embedding of $T^2$ into $S^2$; because it misses a point the local degree formula implies your map is both degree 1 and 0.

Comment: @MikeMiller how can you say that this map is degree 1 map?

Comment: @Anubhav.K: An embedding between spaces of the same dimension is a local homeomorpism. Use the local degree formula to see that if $x$ is in the image, the degree is the number of points in $f^{-1}(x)$: one.

Comment: @MikeMiller the way Hatcher has defined degree, it says that $f: S^n \to S^n$

Comment: You can define it for any closed oriented manifold, whose top homology is automatically $\Bbb Z$. The proof of the local degree theorem goes through just fine in this context.

Comment: @MikeMiller I need to think about this , I've never thought of such a generalization...in that case your solution looks fine to me, I'd only that much doubt regarding the dedinition of degree

Answer (score 13):

Let $F : \mathbb S^1 \times \mathbb S^1 \to \mathbb R^2$. Then the image is closed as $\mathbb S^1 \times\mathbb S^1$ is compact. On the other hand, if $F$ is injective, then the restriction to each small neighborhood $V \subset \mathbb S^1 \times \mathbb S^1$ is also injective. The [invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain) shows that $F(V)$ is open, and so the image of $F$ is also open. But that is nonsense as the only open and closed nonempty subset in $\mathbb R^2$ is $\mathbb R^2$.

Note that there is nothing special about the torus. Every compact surface cannot be embedded to $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @user99914 : Where does that argument fail if you try to embed $T^2$ in  $\mathbb R^3 $?

Comment: Maybe because IOD requires that $V$ and $F(V)$ live in $\mathbb R^n$ for the same n, I guess.

Answer (score 11):

Suppose there is an embedding of $T^2$ in the plane. Since the complete graph $K_5$ can be drawn on the torus without crossings, then it follows that it can also be drawn in the plane. But [it can't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski's_theorem).

Comment: This "only" depends on the Jordan curve theorem.

Answer (score 6):

If you allow the Invariance of Domain theorem into your algebraic topology toolbox, here's what you can do.

Since $T^2$ is compact, the "radius function" $r(x) = |f(x)|$ has a maximum value $R \ge 0$, achieved at some point $x_M \in T^2$. It follows that $\text{image}(f)$ does not contain any open ball centered on $f(x_M)$.

Now choose a subset $B \subset T^2$ containing $x_M$ with a homeomorphism between $B$ and the closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $x_M$ corresponds to the origin of $\mathbb{R}^2$. The restriction $f | B$ is a continuous bijection onto its image and is therefore a homeomorphism onto its image.

The restriction $f | \text{interior}(B)$ then violates the invariance of domain theorem: it's domain is homeomorphic to an open ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and that restriction is an injective continuous map, but its image contains $f(x_M)$ and contains no point further from the origin than $f(x_M)$ and is therefore not open.

Comment: I see, so this does not contradict that the torus can be embedded in $\mathbb R^3$, since, Invariance of domain does not hold between Euclidean spaces of different dimension.