# Is $n$-dim manifold which is immersed in $\mathbb{R}^n$ diffeomorphic to a ball?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional smooth **compact oriented** manifold with boundary which is immersed in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (codimension zero). Must $M$ be diffeomorphic to a ball with boundary (the closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$)?

Does anything change if we assume $M$ is simply-connected? or that it can be immersed in $\mathbb{R}^n$ without self-intersections?

**Edit:** There are (probably many) non-simply connected examples. It seems the interesting case is the simply-connected one.

Comment: Consider the half open interval?

Comment: What about solid torus

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Thanks, nice idea... Your example (the half open interval) is simply connected and of course can be immersed in $\mathbb{R}$ without self-intersections. Can you think on a simply-connected example in higher dimensions? (Also, I was actually interested in compact examples but forgot to mention this)

Comment: compact one does not exists: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1519028/torus-cannot-be-embedded-in-mathbb-r2

Comment: @JohnMa I am not sure I understand your comment. Isn't the closed unit ball an example for a manifold with boundary which is immersed in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (via the standard inclusion). I think the argument you are referring to (about the open+closed+connectedness issue) "fails" at the boundary. Am I wrong?

Comment: Clearly I ignored the word "with boundary" in the question.

Comment: Anyway you can just pick any open set in $\mathbb R^n$ with smooth boundary. Even when you assume that it is simply connected, there are lots of counterexamples.

Comment: As for more interesting examples, each open stably parallelizable $n$-manifold admits an immersion in $R^n$. For instance, every open orientable 3-dimensional manifold immerses in $R^3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider any emebdded compact submanifold of dimanions $k$ in $\bf R^n$, say $V$. Then a tubular neighbourhood $W$ of $V$ is simply connected, but not a ball (it has the same homotopy type than $V$. For instance if $V=S^2$ is the unit two-sphere in $\bf R^3$ the set $1/2\leq x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 1+1/2$ is a compact simply connected manifold with the same homotopy type than a sphere, hence simply connected and not contractible. 
If the codimension of $V$ is at least two, the boundary of $W$ is connected.

Answer (score 7):

Consider a closed annulus in $\mathbb{R}^2 $. It is not even homeomorphic to a closed disk.